# Cannot get tagged photos

Tags: php, instagram

In my application I'm trying to display the most recent photos for a specific hashtag. For example, I would like to get let's say the last 50 photos tagged with the word *hello*. To do this, I've had a look at [this](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) link, where they say this is the correct endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

But, providing a correct access token (previously obtained with a login by the user) and replacing {tag-name} with the *hello*, the response from the server is empty:

```
{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "data": [], "meta": {"code": 200}}
```

So, no photos are returned. 
I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need tag photos and no more, you dont have to use api, token etc. You can get `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{tag}/?__a=1&max_id={max_id}` to receive JSON with array of photos. Parameter `&max_id={max_id}` is optionally.